# Basic HTML login form

Tags: html, forms, authentication

**Hi there!**

So i had this figured out some years back, but i cant seem to find the tutorial again or any backup.

Basically it was a simple login form that sends the user to a specified URL if the text is correct.

Something like **if input type text is "custom text" and input type password is "custom text" then input type submit button go to ahref "custom url"**

```html
<div>
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="username">
</div>
<p></p>
<div>
    <label for="pass">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="pass" name="password" minlength="8" required="">
</div>

<input type="submit" value="Sign in">
```

Funny because it was so basic and had no fancy CSS or javascript if I remember correctly. Again, I used it years go, can't really remember it properly.

So it doesn't use any database or any other advanced stuff (for me), It used to work with more names and passwords, not just one, like demo name and demo pass.

Think of it as a simple webpage locked with a password, if you want to access it, enter password, a custom word, if the work is correct, the button sends you to a custom url.

I'm just gonna leave this here and hopefully you can help.

**Thanks!**

I tried to make a basic, simple HTML form that people can login via custom name and password that if they insert correctly, the submit button will send them to a custom url page.

Comment: You realize this tutorial you're talking about is something that is very generic? Any tutorial about a form with name/password is going to help you create such a project. Now where you want to redirect is up to you and we obviously can't give an answer that is going to be relevant for the community. If you have a question about code that isn't working, you would want to copy/paste your code in your question and provide the context and the goal that you are trying to solve. Please read the stackoverflow.com/tour again to better understand what questions you can ask or answers you can give.

Comment: I'm really sorry to hear that. I just joined for this matter. I'm not really familiar with this very generic stuff you are telling me about and i did post a screenshot of the code.

Comment: We all start somewhere. Just make sure the questions are concise. And it is better to post the code instead of taking a screenshot, so others can use it to test themselves and provide a solution afterwards :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My apoligies!** It does involves some javascript.

Haven't stopped looking and i solved it, i guess, maybe it helps anyone who comes across same trouble as me so i'm just gonna post it.

Its rough around the edges, so no CSS but worth it.

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Javascript Login Form Validation</title>
<!-- Include CSS File Here -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css"/>
<!-- Include JS File Here -->
<script src="js/login.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<div class="main">
<form id="form_id" method="post" name="myform">
<label>USER:</label>
<input type="text" name="username" id="username"/>
<label>PASS:</label>
<input type="password" name="password" id="password"/>
<input type="button" value="LOGIN" id="submit" onclick="validate()"/>
</form>

<br>
<br>
username is <b>asd</b> and password is <b>123</b>

</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<!--THE JS JAVASCRIPT PART BELOW-->

<head>
<script>

var attempt = 4; // Variable to count number of attempts.
// Below function Executes on click of login button.
function validate() {
    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    if (username == "asd" && password == "123") {
        alert("Login successfully");
        window.location = "success.html"; // Redirecting to other page.
        return false;
    } else {
        attempt--; // Decrementing by one.
        alert("You have left " + attempt + " attempt;");
        // Disabling fields after 3 attempts.
        if (attempt == 0) {
            document.getElementById("username").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("password").disabled = true;
            document.getElementById("submit").disabled = true;
            return false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
</head>
```

Comment: A major problem with this solution is that the JavaScript file is going to be on the user's computer and they can view it and see the password. So it is not secure.

Comment: In order to make it secure you have to send the username and password that the user entered to a server and run the `validate()` logic there and then you can send them secret information if their credentials are correct.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of button I have used an `<a>` tag with encapsulated link:

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.